# Remove broken path in master branch

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have done a direct commit in master branch and it turned out to be a mess,**Can anyone let me know how to undo the commits or remove the broken path in master branch**.

**All branches**
 [image]

**Master Branch, here the flow is broken.**
[image]

**Branches screen shot**
[image]

Comment: Use `git revert` to functionally undo changes to your published `master` branch.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen IF i delete the branches which have shown above will it be fine? i will check the it revert, Thanks a lot for the info .

Comment: Also can it be done directly on the bitbucket interface?

Answer (score 0):

> `git-revert *commit ID*` - Revert some existing commits (An 'undo' command)

It will simply create a new commit that is the opposite of an existing commit (the one that is broken in your case).